# AngularJS select multiple causes page jump

Tags: angularjs

I am having a very frustrating issue with AngularJS where the page is jumping down to the select element if the model is updated somewhere else. Check out this plunker, where I update the model via a checkbox and then the page jumps down to the select multiple element. Does not happen when multiple is not specified (in my real working example I need multiple set).

Anyone have a fix for this or some input? Thanks.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EByAPb?p=preview

```
  Check me to select: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected"><br/>

  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

  <select multiple>
    <option>Hello!</option>
    <option id="greet" ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Thanks, correct plunker link updated in question.

Comment: Not sure if you are experiencing this in other browsers, but seems to be a bug in Chrome. Checkout: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423256 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=430654

Comment: I'm on a Mac in the latest version of Chrome. Internal users of my product have reported the bug on Windows as well, I will confirm which browser... Yeah they are on Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't an AngularJS bug, but a "**Select elements cause automated scroll on page load**" bug.

As commented by @tasseKATT, this a known Chrome specific browser issue. It looks like the fix has been merged into chromium, and so this should hopefully fix itself soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423256

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=430654

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to push the browser back to the top:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.refocus = function() {
    $anchorScroll(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 Check me to select: <input id="scrollHere" type="checkbox" ng-model="selected" ng-click="refocus()"><br/>
  
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  
  <select multiple>
    <option>Hello!</option>
    <option id="greet" ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
  </select>
   </body>

</html>
```

or, scroll specifically to the element in question by assigning it an `id` and setting `$location.hash` before calling `$anchorScroll()`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.refocus = function() {
    $location.hash('scrollToHere');
    $anchorScroll(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 Check me to select: <input id="scrollToHere" type="checkbox" ng-model="selected" ng-click="refocus()"><br/>
  
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  
  <select multiple>
    <option>Hello!</option>
    <option id="greet" ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
  </select>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if we were not at the top? That's a good suggestion but not really a solution I can use. I'd rather eliminate the scroll to instead of adding a work around to correct it after the fact.

Comment: I agree, but if this is a bug/quirk specific to Chrome, I'm not sure what else can be done about it. I've added an alternative solution that scrolls to the checkbox instead of to the top of the page.